# JQuery Preventing Multiple Back Quotes on Input Box

Tags: jquery, keydown, keycode

[image]I have the following code that only allows a user to enter any number from the keyboard
or Num Pad and single decimal point. It's works fairly well but I discovered that
it doesn't prevent multiple back quotes (see <kbd>`</kbd> button under the Esc key) from being entered. Any ideas why the following doesn't work for `KeyCode = 223`? I call the following function using a keydown() Event and using i'm JQuery 1.10.2, Crome and Firefox.

```
var keyCode = event.which || event.keyCode;
var isShift = event.shiftKey ? true : false;
if(isShift){
    switch(keyCode){
        case 16:
            break;
        default:
            //Allow user to use Shift and End 35, Home 36, Left Arrow 37, Right Arrow 39, Tab 9.
            if(keyCode!= 35 && keyCode!= 36 && keyCode!= 37 && keyCode!= 39 && keyCode!= 9) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
    }
       //Allow delete 46, Tab 9, Backspace 8, Shift 16, End 35, Home 36, Left Arrow 37, Right Arrow 39.
}else if(keyCode != 46 && keyCode != 9 && keyCode != 8 && keyCode != 16 && keyCode != 35 && keyCode != 36 && keyCode != 37 && keyCode != 39){   
            if(((keyCode != 190 && keyCode != 110) || $(inputBox).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (keyCode < 48 || keyCode > 57 && keyCode != 96 && keyCode != 97 && keyCode != 98 && keyCode != 99 && keyCode != 100 && keyCode != 101 && keyCode != 102 && keyCode != 103 && keyCode != 104 && keyCode != 105)) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
}
```

Comment: It seems to work, I suppose. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/728wj/).

Comment: Thanks fior adding a Fiddle.  If you look at your example it still accepts multiple back quotes ``` characters which I'm trying to prevent!

Comment: It seems to work as you intend in the JSFiddle j809 posted? Is it still not working fro you?

Comment: No it's not working, I'm still able to enter multiple back quotes, are you using Crome and the key directly under Esc?

Comment: I am unable to input ` characters in that fiddle and I am using Chrome on OSX.

Comment: See image of JSFiddle that j809 posted.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason why it is not detecting the backtick is your keyboard settings, I just tested this and can confirm, that changing your keyboard settings to English (United Kingdom) and making it the default keyboard language, I changed from English (Irish) which would not stop the backtick from been entered. When changed to English (United Kingdom) it would not allow me to input the backtick.

1. Windows 7
2. Goto -> Control Panel
3. Clock, Region & Language
4. Change keyboards or other input methods
5. Keyboard & Languages Tab
6. Change Keyboards
7. Add -> English (United Kingdom) -> Keyboard -> United Kingdom
8. Click Apply
9. Set it as your default keyboard language
10. Go to Language Bar -> Select United Kingdom
11. Test j809's fiddle again.

So the keyCodes are actually determined by the keyboard language, makes sense the classic example of US keyboards @ symbol is SHIFT + 2, UK @ symbol is SHIFT + (Key to left of Hash Key)

[Video Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4dxkhthoe53206y/Keyboard_test.mp4)

Comment: This is not a real answer(solution), but more the reason why this is happening.